# error 'document' is not defined : eslint / React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, jsx, jsdom

I'm building a React app, with create-react-app.

I got the following error when running ESLint:
`8:3  error  'document' is not defined  no-undef.`

My app runs without error, but I got this ESLint error in 2 files.
See one of those `.jsx` files and my ESLint configuration.

index.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "plugins": [
      "react",
      "jsx-a11y",
      "import"
  ],
  "env": {
    "jest": true
  }
};
```

How can I fix this ? For the moment I will simply ignore both files ... but I'd rather find a long term solution.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Add `"browser": true` your `env` to include global variables (like document, window, etc.)

See the [ESLint environment documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments) for more information.

Comment: It not clear what to do, where to add this, what file?

Comment: @zishe See the OP, in eslintrc.js has a "env" property. See the ESLint documentation to see how to configure it https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Comment: should i remove `node: true` ?

Answer (score 48):

set an env property in you eslint.rc file, e.g.

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Although @Locus answer is ok, but this is a better solution as it's not dependent to a link (which might got broken on day) and it describes the steps to solve the probelm

Answer (score 8):

If you have `.eslintrc.json` file then add following code snippet.

```
{
    ...otherSettings,
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true
    }
}
```

if you do not have `.eslintrc.json` then you can add these settings in you `package.json` file.

```
{
    ...otherSettings,
    "eslintConfig": {
      "globals": {
        "window": true
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In your `package.json`, specify the test environment for jest as `"jsdom"` as follows:

```
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom"
  }
```

I faced the same issue and it worked well for me.

Comment: No clue why this isn't the top result on google. It's definitely the solution. I didn't realize what the facebook react test script was doing with its -env=jsdom command line argument

Answer (score 0):

Set this in your .eslintrc file:

```
env: {
  browser: true
}
```

So eslint will recognise these browser related globals