# "ReferenceError: document is not defined" when trying to test a create-react-app project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

This is my `__tests__/App.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from '../src/containers/App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
});

// sanity check
it('one is one', () => {
  expect(1).toEqual(1)
});
```

And this is the output I get when running `yarn test`:

```
FAIL  __tests__/App.js
  ● renders without crashing

    ReferenceError: document is not defined

      at Object.<anonymous>.it (__tests__/App.js:6:15)

  ✕ renders without crashing (1ms)
  ✓ one is one

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.128s, estimated 1s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

Do I need to import another module in order for `document` to be available here?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: document isn't available in a node environment. you should check out enzyme for testing react components http://airbnb.io/enzyme/

Comment: you could also use karma for testing https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/index.html

Comment: I can't answer specifically as I've never tried to use the document object in Jest tests, but https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme is generally the goto tool for testing React components and is definitely worth checking out.

Comment: great - needed to use enzyme to get it working! thx all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error 'document' is not defined : eslint / React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42377038/error-document-is-not-defined-eslint-react)

Comment: I just started running into this issue when upgrading from Jest v26 to v27, and it turns out the default `testEnvironment` [changed](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/9874) from `jsdom` to `node`.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

For me either of these worked

In package.json file adding test script env flag

```
"scripts": {
   "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom"
}
```

Using enzyme

```
 import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

 it('renders without crashing', () => {
  shallow(<App />);
 });
```

Answer (score 43):

I set the value in `jest.config.js` to below and it worked:

```
testEnvironment: 'jsdom'
```

Comment: Thanks. I like this answer cause I don't have to edit package.json myself.

Comment: I think this is the best answer!

Comment: this is the best answer because use the jest config file to set up this environment, brilliant.

Comment: This worked, just make sure you have `jest-environment-jsdom`.

Answer (score 26):

Placing the comment at the top of your unit-test source

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
```

signals jest to mock document and window.

Comment: thanks, this was the only thing that worked!

Answer (score 17):

In the package.json if using jest

```
"scripts":{
      "test": "jest --env=jsdom"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have just run into this issue, September 2021. I am learning testing in react and I resolved this issue by entering node_modules folder.
Inside that folder there is a jest folder. Inside jest folder there is a package.json file.
Inside that package.json file I inserted one thing. Similar to what someone mentioned above.

### **package.json file**

`"testEnvironment": "jsdom"`

I know generally I should not edit node_modules folder, but just for thesake of continuing to learn this will have to do.

I do not know whether some other solution would be necessary for a more serious project.

Comment: It would be better to add this in the `package.json` under the `jest` object

Comment: Yes, William, I found that solution later. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the solution was:

1. Add field `testEnvironment: "jsdom"` to `jest.config.js`
2. `npm i jest-environment-jsdom -D`

Answer (score 2):

put this on top of your index.test.js ( or test file). Don´t put it on the middle or end.

/** * @jest-environment jsdom */

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I am using Mocha instead of Jest and I had to assign manually jsdom to the global.document. May not sound like a perfect solution but it's any.

In .mocharc.yml add a path to the file jsdom-loader.js:

```
require: ['@babel/register',
          'test/jsdom-loader']
```

jsdom-loader.js

```
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
const environment = new JSDOM('');
const { document } = environment.window;
global.document = document;
```

Comment: this solution is working well for me in jest and allowing me to run server side tests next to react component tests in the same jest setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `create-react-app`, make sure to run `yarn test` instead of `yarn jest` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the file extension from `myfile.test.ts` => `myfile.test.tsx` ... in addition to the above solutions.
Indeed, I had a TS error with `@testing-library/react` at `render(<MyComponent/>)` in my `.test.ts` file, and by changing the extension all problems were solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem in `vitest`. The default environment in Vitest is a Node.js environment. If you are building a web application, you can use browser-like environment through either `jsdom` or `happy-dom` instead. [doc](https://vitest.dev/config/#environment)
There are three ways you can add env for your test:

1. In `package.json` file add

```json
{
   "scripts":{
       "test": "vitest --environment=jsdom"
   }
}
```

2. In `vitest.config.ts` file add:

```js
export default defineConfig({
   environment: 'jsdom'
})
```

3. Add the below code at the top of your test file

```js
/**
 * @vitest-environment happy-dom
 */
```