# ReactJS Jest Puppeteer tests no longer working: ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: reactjs, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

**Scenario**

`npm test` used to work without issue. Over the course of a month or so (I neglected tests) something changed and now I receive `ReferenceError: document is not defined` when trying to run Jest-Puppeteer tests via `npm test`.

This error shows up even with `document` removed so it seems like a puppeteer issue but I'm not sure why this is showing up now. I've checked out code from over a month ago and the tests still work but so much has changed that it's difficult to chase down the actually issue.

**Attempted Solutions**

- upgrade node
- reinstall npm packages
- revert `jest-puppeteer.config.js` to previous version
- add `@jest-environment jsdom` to tests which fixes the document issue but then causes `ReferenceError: page is undefined`

**Question**

How can I troubleshoot this problem short of starting over from scratch? That said, I'm prepared to start over if that's what it's going to take, which sometimes it does.

**Code**

*this is a basic jest file*

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
import {Provider} from "react-redux"
import mockState from "./mocks/mockState"
import configureStore from "redux-mock-store"
import ShallowRenderer from 'react-test-renderer/shallow'
import API from '../src/API'
import getNavigationResponse from '../src/nocks/getNavigation'
import expectedNavigationState from "./static/expectedNavigationState"
import pageObjects from "./static/pageObjects"
import utils from './utils'
import constants from '../src/constants'


describe('API tests', () => {
    beforeEach(async() => {
        await page.goto('http://localhost:3000');
        await page.setViewport({ width: 900, height: 600 });
        await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/');
        await page.evaluate(() => {
            document.getElementById('root').classList.add('animated-test');
        });
        await page.waitForSelector(pageObjects.navFactory);
    });

    // PASS
    test('API data to be in store', async () => {
        await page.waitForSelector(pageObjects.primaryNavLink);

        // get state from root
        const store = await utils.getStore();

        expect(store[0].navigation.urlHashMap).toEqual(expectedNavigationState);
    });

    test.todo('Make sure content==true on vanity urls (home)')

    test.todo('Make sure content==false on url items with children (visitor)')

    // PASS
    test('API cancel should cancel the API request', async () => {
        API.dispatch = () => {

        };
        API.fetch(constants.NAVIGATION_HREF, 'API_FETCH_TYPE_NAVIGATION');
        const promiseCanceled = API.cancel('API_FETCH_TYPE_NAVIGATION');
        expect(promiseCanceled).hasOwnProperty('promise');
        expect(promiseCanceled).hasOwnProperty('cancel');
    });
});
```

## ** EDIT **

From what I can find out, this "ReferenceError" seems to be a babel error that is caused because babel can't seem to figure out what "document" is. I traced down where the issue is happening and it is within a third party plugin so I left a note on the developer's github page in the mean time. Currently my "solution" is to comment this test out - I'll put more effort into this again when I have time to find a proper solution

## ** EDIT 2 **

If I add `<rootDir>/node_modules/react-json-view/dist/main.js` to babel config's `transformIgnorePatterns` then I get a different error of

```
ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
```

Which is odd because I explicitly have `import "regenerator-runtime/runtime"` at the top. This seems to be a step closer but I'm not sure. I switched back to `babel-polyfill` (deprecated) just to try it but ended with a different error of `TypeError: jest: failed to cache transform results`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you can do something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46261861/332578) which is to add:

```
npm test --env=jsdom
```

But since I also need Puppeteer's environment there's a clash because node only seems to support ONE environment.

Ultimately I removed the troubled plugin.